# Bind Multiple Sites With Separate SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-6

I am going to host 2 web sites (siteA.company.com and siteB.company.com) on the same IIS (version 6.2). I have requested a ssl cert for each site - certA with siteA.company.com as SAN and certB with siteA.company.com as SAN. I've imported both certs to IIS and then bind certA to siteA and certB to siteB. When I browse https://siteB.company.com, i can see it's secured by certB and works as expected. But when i browse https://siteA.company.com, it still shows secured by certB instead of certA. Is it possible to bind each site with a different ssl cert on the same IIS? How to set that up?

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the question, I did some research. It seems like you can only have 1 cert per IP:PORT combination, so it's impossible to use a separate ssl cert for each site with same IP. Using a cert with both DNS names as SAN seems a way to go. Will give it a try.